# Pip command for upgrading a specific source archive

Tags: python, pip, egg

I installed a source archive package xxx-1.0.tar.gz using the command

```
sudo pip install xxx-1.0.tar.gz
```

Now, I want to upgrade it to version 2.0.  When I use the command

```
sudo pip install xxx-2.0.tar.gz
```

it complains about missing /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xxx-1.0-py2.7.egg' file

What am I missing? Is it okay to upgrade a package using install command.
Why does pip still look for older version of egg file?

Answer (score 0):

```
pip list --outdated | cut -d ' ' -f1 | xargs -n1 pip install -U
```

This will list packages like

```
xxx (A.B.C) - Latest: D.E.F.G
```

`cut -d ' ' -f1`, will get the first column i.e 'xxx'

`-d ' '` sets space as the delimiter

`-n1` will be assigned to 1 (number of arguments).

`xargs` will run the command `pip install -U`